# $.ajax with JSONP causes IE8 to throw security warning

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-8, youtube, jsonp

I have a https site. I'm running LifeRay on Tomcat. I'm using the following URL:

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ID?v=2&alt=jsonc

and

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: function (obj) {
        processData(obj);
    }
});
```

to get the data and then processing it. It works on all the browsers. The only problem is that I get a security warning in IE8.

Question 1: Is there any way to get the JSON data securely and processing the data without IE throwing any warning messages?

Question 2: How and where can I set this: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://youtube.com`, so that maybe IE won't throw any warning messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ID?v=2&alt=jsonc

Since you are in https, IE wants all resources accessible within that domain to be secured. I feel previously you were using **http://** in the request URL of youtube. Change it https, it may solve the security warning issue.

If a secure page loads any nonsecure resource, its going to throw the warning. The only way to get around it is to load everything from https.

Here you are trying to load a non secured resource (http://gdata.youtube....) in the secured website.

HTH